# Excel VBA code for selection of a range and pasting a text in the selected range

Tags: excel, vba, range, selection

Let's assume I have selected a range `(B5-B30)` by mouse. I need a VBA code that selects exactly the same cells in another column `(A5-A30)` for me . I need to paste a certain text into `(A5-A30)` then.

Is there a VBA code that does this?

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
selection.offset(0,-3).select
```

Change -3 to how many columns, -1 is one to the left, 1 is 1 to the right.

You can change the 0 if you wish to move a number of rows too.

If you want to just paste without selecting, do this:

```
Selection.Offset(0, -3).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Change xlPasteAll to xlPasteValues if you want values rather than formulas.